# How can i change by esp8266 baudrate, as I accidentally changed the baudrate to something else(which I dont remember)?

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, baud-rate

```
//In order to connect, 

SoftwareSerial esp8266(2,3); 

// the TX pin of esp8266 is connected to pin 3 of 
// arduino uno and RX pin is connected to 2    
// we need to pass baud rate to begin function

void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  esp8266.begin(???); // what should i do in order to make it work?
}
```

What should i do in order to make it work?

Comment: Simplest to just re-flash the AT firmware. Follow one of the many thousands of tutorials, or find all the answers here telling you how.

Comment: I tried to flash, everywhere it is asking for baud rate to communicate to esp8266,i tried 9600 which is configured for my arduino, it doesnt work.

Comment: You need the *bootloader* baud rate. Try 57600.

Comment: Hi Majenko, i tried all the possible standard baud rates(including 57600), did not work :/

Comment: I couldn't find a solution, So, bought new esp8266 and worked with it default baudrate (115200).

Answer (score 1):

I encountered a similar situation where I accidentally set the baudrate to 8000 with the AT commands.

Thankfully I remembered the baud rate I set, so I used PuttY to create a serial communication with the port with the weird 8000 baud rate and changed the baud rate back to 9600.

The method can be found here: http://flower-platform.com/2015/12/16/esp8266-with-at-commands-connect-from-pc-with-putty/

The AT command I used to change the baud rate:
`AT+UART_DEF=9600,8,1,0,0`

Comment: I'm not going to vote this down, but you know "which I dont remember)" in the question title is probably designed to discourage this answer.